# Php 7.3 extension imagick and gmagick on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, nginx, imagemagick

How can i install php extension imagick and gmagick on ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 
i tried imagick using :

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install libmagickwand-dev
sudo peclX.Y-sp install imagick
```

But got error

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo pecl7.3-sp install imagick
sudo: pecl7.3-sp: command not found
```

Also tell me about gmagick, I have installed both graphicsmagick and imagemagick just need to install php extention for both of them.

I am using Php7.3 ondrej,

```
Installed: php7.3 php-pear php7.3-curl php7.3-dev php7.3-gd php7.3-mbstring php7.3-zip php7.3-mysql php7.3-xml
```

Comment: Please run `apt search php-imagick` and see if imagick shows up! Also run the search for `php-gmagick` if both show then install with `sudo apt install php-gmagick php-imagick` My version of php is 7.2 so check and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I use `php7.2` but from the same repo as your version of php. Check if these packages are present with the commands

```
apt search php-imagick | grep php-imagick
apt search php-gmagick | grep php-gmagick
```

If the search turns up positive, install both with the command

```
sudo apt install php-gmagick php-imagick
```

Restart apache afterward with

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```